# Setting custom font after having set TextAppearance in XML, doesn't work

Tags: android

I'm have this text view:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Paragraph3"
    tools:text="Título"/>
```

and trying to apply a custom font programatically after this, using this extension:

```
fun TextView.setCustomFont(font: Int) {
   typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, font)
}
```

but its not work, if I remove the textAppearence from XML everything works.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 1**

Already followed the documentation to setup the fonts: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml

Comment: the style overrides any custom font change that follows. Have you tried using the  fontFamily attribute instead?

Comment: That style its not only font configuration. I need a way to set up the entire style without lose the context and change the font when I need it.

Comment: I assume you have downloaded the appropriate fonts and placed them within the appropriate res folder?

Comment: Already done the proper configuration and using it in other places. Its just iwhen I do the case above that my extension doesnt work

Comment: can you edit the style? If yes just remove the font attribute from there and try using fontFamily instead.

Comment: I dont want to create a style everytime I need to this kind of customization. There's no simple way to this with cohesion?

Comment: also at the bottom of the page on the link you added, it shows you how to create a style within the font family instead. does it make any easier to have different fonts with the same styling perhaps?

Answer (score -2):

I solve this removing textAppearence from XML and doing a setTextAppearence in my code. Since appears that textAppearence xml attribute overrides all font customizations.

This seems to manage it.

Comment: that's not really an answer